# Phonegap - Android App - alter version number?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

just a quick one - can anyone advise how I can alter the version number of my compiled apk?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you compile your application you modify your AndroidManifest.xml file. You'll want to modify the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the manifest tag.

More info can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Not sure what you can do once the apk is compiled.

Comment: You don't need to alter your AndroidManifest.xml file cause when you compile your Android project with cordova/ phonegap the config.xml file from your projects www folder is bound to the compilation process and your AndroidManifest.xml file is update automatically. Just take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple: Just open config.xml file inside your 
`your-project-name/www/`
folder and in the all surrounding note, which e.g. looks like that:
    
`< widget id="com.haibarbe.eurofleurs" version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

edit the version attribute.
You just need to compile your app again and sign it freshly with your formerly created keys.
Thats it.
But remember thats only valid for Android apps, iOS apps do not use that version property but
use your Xcode build version number. Nevertheless that version number is exported to your Xcode project file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to widget tag in **config.xml**

> android-versionCode="30"

Example:

```
<widget id="com.profimedica.ajuro" 
    android-versionCode="29"
    version="0.0.3" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Because Phonegap ignore the AndroidManifest.xml
I assume build.gradle rules is appending number 8 to my version number resulting in 298 due to this code:

```
  if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
  } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
  }
```